# Function get_post_permalink() returns wrong link inside post

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm currently have a link to another posts inside a custom post-type post. I'm building this link with `get_the_permalink($otherPostId);`.

The problem is that even when I pass the correct ID from the other post to the function, it's returning the link of the post where I'm at the moment, instead of the link of the post I want.

I also tried `the_permalink($otherPostId)` and `get_permalink($otherPostId)` and got the same result. It was previously working, but I have no idea what's happening now.

Comment: Could you share the exact code you're using, including the post ID of the other post?

Comment: is `$otherPostId` a variable you're setting earlier in your code, or just an alias for an integer that you're using? And are you using `get_post_permalink()` or `get_the_permalink()`? Your title cites one but your post cites another.

Comment: <?php if(get_featured_admin('description_prp', true ) != ""):?>
                                <p class="description"><?php echo ah_get_featured_admin('description_prp', true );?></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($featuredProperty->ID); ?>" class="ah-btn-detail">View Details</a>

Comment: I tried with get_post_permalink(); too @Myles

Comment: Seems like maybe you're `$featuredProperty` isn't being set correctly, but your code doesn't show how that's being done. You could try editing your post with all the relevant code so we can try to spot the problem.

Comment: $featured= ah_get_featured_admin('property', true );
$featuredProperty = ah_get_featured_post($featured, 'description_prp',, true); <----- It does returns correctly the ID of the other post. (example 002).

The problem is that when I use the method get_post_permalik() or any other sending the post ID 002 it returns the permalink of the post I am at the moment not the permalink of the ID i'm sending @Myles

Comment: Please edit your post to add your code, and please format it nicely. It's really hard to read blocks of code in comments. And are you showing functions from a plugin in there? I'm not sure these are all core wordpress functions. What do you get if you `print_r($featuredProperty)`? Is it just a post ID or an actual post object?